# Regex replace with some condition

Tags: c#, regex

How to replace

```
convert(varchar,CREATED_ON,106)  =>  to_char(CREATED_ON, 'dd/mon/yyyy')
```

similar to below code

```
string ss = Regex.Replace("convert(varchar,CREATED_ON,106)", @"convert(varchar,^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$,106)", "to_char(CREATED_ON, 'dd/mon/yyyy')", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. You haven't specified any replacement rules, so code you've provided basically does what you want - it replaces one string with another. So what is the problem?

Comment: Well, it doesn't work at all yet because the parentheses are unescaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"convert\(\s?varchar\s?,(.*?)\s?,\s?106\s?\)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string original = "convert(varchar,CREATED_ON,106)";

        string replaced = reg.Replace(original, "to_char($1, 'dd/mon/yyyy')");

        Console.WriteLine(replaced);
    }
}
```

or without creating a regex using static method:

```
string ss = Regex.Replace(original, @"convert\(\s?varchar\s?,(.*?)\s?,\s?106\s?\)", "to_char($1, 'dd/mon/yyyy')", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The $1 will get replaced by whats in the first group (.*?).

Comment: @tempsun i added some \s? to the pattern allowing some spaces between the arguments... i dont know what's the to_char function in sql though and the datetime pattern looks wrong too: 'dd/MM/yyyy' think you mean that? is that mysql or some other?

Comment: @tempsun never mind i just found it and the pattern is ok too since this is oracle....